# Unable to add NTLM authentication to my C# MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a C# MVC app and I don't know how to

```
private static IWebHostBuilder CommonHostBuild(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    return builder
        .UseKestrel()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(ConfigureAppConfiguration)
        .ConfigureLogging(ConfigureLogging)
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

and this is my `onStart()` method:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        host = CommonHostBuild(new WebHostBuilder())
            .UseContentRoot(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .UseUrls("http://*:8086")
            .Build();

        host.StartAsync();
    }
```

I need to add this bit which enables NTLM authentication

```
.UseHttpSys()
.UseHttpSys(options =>
{
     options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
})
```

But the class `WebHostBuilder` seems to be missing the `UseHttpSys` method and I don't know why

Comment: Based on the docs, it´s not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderhttpsysextensions.usehttpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostBuilderHttpSysExtensions_UseHttpSys_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostBuilder_

Comment: @Hackerman Well, that is in a different assembly... (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys)

Comment: Yes, you need to add that extension

Comment: @Hackerman Yup, it's in a handy Nuget package!

Comment: Yep...I just want to see that if the OP was able to figure it out on his own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the [`UseHttpSys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderhttpsysextensions.usehttpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostBuilderHttpSysExtensions_UseHttpSys_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostBuilder_) method, you need to add the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys` Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys/)

From the package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys
```

Or from dotnet CLI:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys
```